# Stop autoplay video in webview

Tags: android, webview, autoplay

In webview,

```
<p style="float: left; width: 160px; text-align: left;"><font color="orange">Promotion Video</font></p>
                            <embed style="width: 100%; height: 250px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 0;" src="<?=$User_Video?>"><br><br>
```

and android,

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
```

I load the url in webview, the video play auto.

So I put webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true), but it isn't works.

I want stop autoplay video in webview.

Comment: use webview.pause()

Comment: @YoLo I can't find webview.pause() but find webview.onpause() . And I use that, webview stop load url

Comment: Is there any update on this? I am also facing the same issue